# How to convert this old api mapreduce job code to new mapreduce

Tags: java, http, hadoop, mapreduce

This code below comes from Alex Holmes Hadoop In Practice Ver - 2:
Link: https://github.com/alexholmes/hiped2/tree/master/src/main/java/hip/ch5/http

This mapper of this mapreduce code reads the list of urls from a text file, sends the HTTP request and stores the body content to a text file.

This code is however written based in old mapreduce api and I wanted to convert to new version of mapreduce api. It might be simple as changing JobConf to Job + Configuration and extend new Mapper but I can't make it to work with my code for some reason.

I would rather wait to post my modified code to avoid confusion but the original code is mentioned below:

Mapper Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public final class HttpDownloadMap
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
  private int file = 0;
  private Configuration conf;
  private String jobOutputDir;
  private String taskId;
  private int connTimeoutMillis =
      DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
  private int readTimeoutMillis = DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
  private final static int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5000;
  private final static int DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5000;

  public static final String CONN_TIMEOUT =
      "httpdownload.connect.timeout.millis";

  public static final String READ_TIMEOUT =
      "httpdownload.read.timeout.millis";

  @Override
  public void configure(JobConf job) {
    conf = job;
    jobOutputDir = job.get("mapred.output.dir");
    taskId = conf.get("mapred.task.id");

    if (conf.get(CONN_TIMEOUT) != null) {
      connTimeoutMillis = Integer.valueOf(conf.get(CONN_TIMEOUT));
    }
    if (conf.get(READ_TIMEOUT) != null) {
      readTimeoutMillis = Integer.valueOf(conf.get(READ_TIMEOUT));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                  OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                  Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    Path httpDest =
        new Path(jobOutputDir, taskId + "_http_" + (file++));

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
      URLConnection connection =
          new URL(value.toString()).openConnection();
      connection.setConnectTimeout(connTimeoutMillis);
      connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutMillis);
      is = connection.getInputStream();

      os = FileSystem.get(conf).create(httpDest);

      IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, conf, true);
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeStream(is);
      IOUtils.closeStream(os);
    }

    output.collect(new Text(httpDest.toString()), value);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
  }
}
```

Job Runner/Driver Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;

public final class HttpDownloadMapReduce {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    runJob(args[0], args[1]);
  }

  public static void runJob(String src, String dest)
      throws Exception {
    JobConf job = new JobConf();
    job.setJarByClass(HttpDownloadMap.class);

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(job);
    Path destination = new Path(dest);

    fs.delete(destination, true);

    job.setMapperClass(HttpDownloadMap.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, src);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, destination);

    JobClient.runJob(job);
  }
}
```

Run Configurations:

```
args[0] = "testData/input/urls.txt"
args[1] = "testData/output"
```

urls.txt contains:

```
http://www.google.com 
http://www.yahoo.com
```

Comment: Mapper Class: http://textuploader.com/76sx

Comment: Job Runner Class: http://textuploader.com/76si - code link set to expire in 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

1. Importing the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package instead of the mapred ones.
2. Change the old `OutputCollector` and `Reporter` to `Context` as the new API uses `Context` objects for writing.
3. Change the `JobClient` to `Job` and `JobConf` to `Configuration`.

Comment: Hi Nilay, I did modified the code based on your suggestions but I can't get it to work the way it should. Could you help me debug this, the code is uploaded to these external links. Mapper Class: http://www.textuploader.com/76sx & Job Runner Class: http://www.textuploader.com/76si